# effects of npm install

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

Today morning i was unable to do npm install. i was get self signed cert error, i tried the solution as specified [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more) and it worked.

Now i am unable to send emails from my app using aws-sdk SES API. I am getting this error,

```
   "message": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND", "code": "NetworkingError", "errno": "ENOTFOUND",   "syscall": "getaddrinfo", "region": "us-west-1", "hostname": "email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com", "retryable": true, "time": "2014-02-28T10:47:27.471Z", "_willRetry": false
```

I have another server where i did npm install yesterday, that instance works.

Please help.

Comment: I have already done that and its working. This behavior is after implementing the solution.

Comment: we dint specify the region before initializing SES instance. Once specified it resolved the issue. But wondering how it was working all this while...